# How to detect a bind mount in Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, mount

I am able to detect a bind mount in Trusty by using a mount command:

```
23:22:49 server-trusty vlad ~  > mount | grep custom
/var/lib/custom on /var/lib/custom type none (rw,bind)
23:33:29 server-trusty vlad ~  > mount | grep ' / '
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,discard)
```

But in Xenial, the same test does not work. It outputs the same options as for the source:

```
23:25:33 server-xenial vlad ~ > mount | grep custom
/dev/xvda1 on /var/lib/custom type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
23:30:00 server-xenial vlad ~  > mount | grep ' / '
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
```

Is there a way for an automated script to reliably detect a bind mount on Xenial?